# Does this cause a memory leak (in .NET)?

Tags: .net, memory-management

I have a memory leak question. Will the instances of obj ever be eligible for garbage collection until the class instance of TopClass goes out of scope?

```
public class TopClass
{
  public void MyFunction()
  {
    TestClass obj = new TestClass();
    obj.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => { //Do some code };
    obj = null;
  }
}
```

Furthermore that would make all objects that instantiate a TopClass and invoke MyFunction() to not be eligible for GC right?

I understand that in managed code once the application goes out of scope then all the objects are eligible, but I want to know WHILE my app is running this will cause a memory leak. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. `obj` will be collected all right. Nothing in this code causes a strong reference.

An object can be kept alive by being attached as an event handler, but an object cannot be kept alive by having event handlers.

Comment: Yes, the TestClass instance can be collected right after (or even during) the call to MyFunction.

Answer (score 3):

`obj` will be eligible to garbage collection as soon as you set it too null (but the actual collection will be done later of course). Subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event doesn't create a reference to `obj`, it creates a reference from obj to the instance of `TopClass`. And it won't prevent collection of the `TopClass` instance either, unless it's referenced somewhere else